# Linq grouping by Max not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, max

I have a table with products

```
Id  |  Name      |  Order
1   | product 1  |    5
1   | product 1  |    9
1   | product 1  |    2 
2   | product 2  |    0
3   | product 3  |    1
```

I need to return just the product with the max order number:

```
Id  |  Name      |  Order

1   | product 1  |    9
2   | product 2  |    0 
3   | product 3  |    1
```

tried this but it's not working:

```
var items = (from i in db.products
                 group i by new
                 {
                     i.Id,
                     i.Name,
                     i.Order
                 } into g

                 select new
                 {
                     g.Key.Id,
                     g.Key.Name,
                     Order = g.Where(d => d.Order == g.Max(xx => xx.Order )).First().Order     })
```

but it stills return all the 5 results.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
             group i by new
             {
                 i.Id,
                 i.Name,
                 i.Order
             } into g
```

into

```
             group i by new
             {
                 i.Id,
                 i.Name,
             } into g
```

I think I would also rewrite the the last expression to

```
Order = g.OrderByDescending(xx => xx.Order).First().Order
```

Mostly because I think it is easier to read, but the generated SQL might be more efficient too. But this is just a matter of taste and any performance difference can be verified with SQL Profiler.

Comment: @Rawling, Then you would need to get the name by `g.First().Name` and that would translate into worse SQL (Assuming LINQ2SQL by the `db.products`).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm a little hazy on this. Is that why we're creating a new item to select rather than selecting an existing item from the group, too?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you still have 5 rows is because Order is different for your group by combination. This would be the query if you wanna use the original one, or use the order by to get the max Order.

```
var items = (from i in db.products
                 group i by new
                 {
                     i.Id,
                     i.Name                     
                 } into g

                 select new
                 {
                     g.Key.Id,
                     g.Key.Name,
                     Order = g.Where(d => d.Order == g.Max(xx => xx.Order )).First().Order     })
```